# MediaMetadataRetriever getFrameAtTime: videoframe is a null pointer

Tags: android, frame, media, null-pointer

I´m trying to get a frame of a video, so I´m using MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime() like this:

```
    Uri directorio = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.extremeye/" + R.raw.video);
    media = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    media.setDataSource(this, directorio);

    frame = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.frame);
    Bitmap bmFrame = media.getFrameAtTime();
    frame.setImageBitmap(bmFrame);
```

But the problem is that I get:

> MediaMetadataRetriever getFrameAtTime: videoframe is a null pointer

in the logCat.

I´m sure that the video is compatible with android OS and the MediaMetadataRetriever loads it because I can get its metadata description without problems in a 2.3.3 OS version.

I don´t know why I can´t get the frame but if I use a 4.2 OS version, it works perfectly. I tried to change the codec and the format of the video but it doesn´t work... I suppose that it´s a problem of format compatibility but I don´t know what I can do...

Thanks!!

Comment: same rabish thing. I download a video converter and I made sure that the video was compatible by H.246 codec but I'm still get null pointer.

Comment: (Veo que eres español así que te contesto en español mejor jajaja) Esta clase funciona realmente mal, creo que el fallo ocurre dependiendo del punto exacto del vídeo del cual quieres extraer el frame. A parte de este fallo también está el de compatibilidad con formatos, no funciona con la Api 10... Al final encontré una libreria externa que funciona genial: https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever. Me costó un poco añadirla a mi proyecto pero creo que ya está solucionado. Pruébala porque a mi me ha salvado... Ya me dirás cómo te va!!

Comment: gracias Gonzalo!! I'll try to add this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I´m using FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever class from [this external library](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) and works great!!

Comment: The library is too big ! when I compile it in my bundle .. my apk size jumped from 2 MB to  16 MB .... is there a way to fix this problem ?